# parameter tampering for dropdownlist - ASP.NET

Tags: drop-down-menu, parameters

I have a question, if I have set the following properties in my web.config

`viewStateEncryptionMode="Always" enableViewStateMac="true"`

Will it be still possible to tamper values of controls on my web form?
For e.g if I have a dropdown with 3 possible values e.g. "IND", "AU", "ML" can someone still tamper this dropdown and send junk data like `$%^`?

Answer (score 0):

With those settings, ViewState should protect against things like thas - you should get an **Invalid Viewstate** error if a value is posted back which didn't exist at the time the page was requested.

Of course with other input controls (such as a TextBox or Hidden field), they are designed to have a value specified by the client without checking it's one of a list of values from the server. In those cases, don't just rely on the ViewState - validate the input yourself too.